# C# Regular Expression to get data

Tags: c#

Hi everyone i want to get data json form this file with regular expression, this data i get from web router

```js
//
nvram = {
 'wan_domain': '',
 'wan_gateway': '10.10.1.1',
 'wan_gateway_get': '125.162.136.1',
 'wan_get_domain': '',
 'wan_hostname': 'Gatsu-Router',
 'wan_hwaddr': '50:46:5D:00:C8:89',
 'wan_ipaddr': '125.162.138.160',
 'wan_netmask': '255.255.255.255',
 'wan_proto': 'pppoe',
 'wan_run_mtu': '1492',
 'web_pb': ''};

//
   
wlstats = [ { radio: 1, client: 0, channel:  3, mhz: 2422, rate: 144, ctrlsb: 'none', nbw: 20, rssi: 0, noise: -86, intf: 0 }
,{ radio: 1, client: 0, channel:  149, mhz: 5745, rate: 900, ctrlsb: 'lower', nbw: 40, rssi: 0, noise: -99, intf: 0 }
];
```

so iget this data

```js
nvram = {
 'wan_domain': '',
 'wan_gateway': '10.10.1.1',
 'wan_gateway_get': '125.162.136.1',
 'wan_get_domain': '',
 'wan_hostname': 'Gatsu-Router',
 'wan_hwaddr': '50:46:5D:00:C8:89',
 'wan_ipaddr': '125.162.138.160',
 'wan_netmask': '255.255.255.255',
 'wan_proto': 'pppoe',
 'wan_run_mtu': '1492',
 'web_pb': ''};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to parse data from router. That is easier than using regular expressions.

According to shree.pat18 comment, here is small working example how to use that:

TestJson.cs:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestConsole.TestClasses {

    class RouterInfo {

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "wan_gateway")]
    public string Gateway { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "wan_run_mtu")]
    public int Mtu { get; set; }

    // add here other fields

}

class JsonTest {

    public void Test() {
        string routerData = @"{
'wan_domain': '',
'wan_gateway': '10.10.1.1',
'wan_gateway_get': '125.162.136.1',
'wan_get_domain': '',
'wan_hostname': 'Gatsu-Router',
'wan_hwaddr': '50:46:5D:00:C8:89',
'wan_ipaddr': '125.162.138.160',
'wan_netmask': '255.255.255.255',
'wan_proto': 'pppoe',
'wan_run_mtu': '1492',
'web_pb': ''}";
        RouterInfo info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RouterInfo>(routerData);
        // here you can work with RouterInfo "info" object
    }
}
}
```

You should add Json.NET library to your project, use NuGet for that.

Comment: I realise you might not have enough rep to add this as a comment, but you should consider posting a short code sample if you are providing only the link to the library.